# How to fetch audio files from phone and SD card and play them?

Tags: c#, audio, windows-phone

How to fetch audio files from phone and SD card and play them?
I'm just a designer but I understand code when I see it.

So what I need is a code *that does just that.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Petzold showed us this.  Press a button, play a random tune out of the library.

XAML:

```
            <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="177,160,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

C# Code Behind:

using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Random random = new Random();  // new random variable
        MediaLibrary mediaLib = new MediaLibrary(); // this is where it grabs your whole music library and enumerates everything.  If you break here, you can see it.

        AlbumCollection albums = mediaLib.Albums;  // pick which song you want.
        Album album = albums[random.Next(albums.Count)];
        SongCollection songs = mediaLib.Songs;
        Song song = songs[random.Next(songs.Count)];
        MediaPlayer.Play(song); // this plays the song.
    }
```

Its as simple as that.

Comment: oh...ok, what about template you get in visual studio 2010? (audio playback)